# When attempting to open a path with CreateFileW, does ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED always indicate that the file exists?

Tags: windows, winapi

When using `CreateFileW` with `OPEN_EXISTING` it can sometimes fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. As far as I'm aware this always means the file exists but that you can't open it for whatever reason. However, are there any cases where it could fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` but the file does not exist?

Comment: Windows permissions are based on the file. The parent folder's permissions don't matter. So denying permissions on the parent folder will still allow you to access the file (or at least try to).

Comment: @RemyLebeau It gives `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, I just tried. Interesting, so even if one doesn't have any permission to a folder one can still check whether a file of known name is there.

Comment: @ChrisD - *The parent folder's permissions don't matter.* - only if we have [`SeChangeNotifyPrivilege`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/bypass-traverse-checking) privilege. but usual we have this.

Comment: usual yes. this mean that file or folder exist. more exactly always call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` because many different nt errors mapped to single `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. for example `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` mapped to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` but this status mean that name point to directory instead file and nothing say - are you have access to this directory at all. or `STATUS_FILE_DELETED`

Comment: almost always - yes, this mean that file or folder with such path exist, or in deleting process. for more exactly info better call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` instead `GetLastError`. and system api `RtlDoesFileExists_U` interpret `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` as exist file case.

Comment: For future reference, I tried disabling the "Bypass Traverse Checking" permission for a process (aka `SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME` aka "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege"). When a folder is not accessible but the file exists it produces `ACCESS_DENIED` and `ERROR_NAME_NOT_FOUND` if it doesn't. So it still works in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in general - yes. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` on `CreateFileW` call mean that file or folder exist. however the source of error - was `NTSTATUS` code, which than converted to win32 code. problem here that frequently multiple different `NTSTATUS` converted to single win32 error code. especially for `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` ( not less that 25 different status converted to single code 5 - `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`). for get source `NTSTATUS` better call native api direct or `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` in place (or together) `GetLastError`.

for example `CreateFileW` call `NtCreateFile` with `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE` option usually (if you not set `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag) and if with given name exist folder (directory) - status `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` will be returned. of course this by sense have nothing common with access denied, but will be converted to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` .

special (undocumented) system api:

`NTSYSAPI BOOLEAN NTAPI RtlDoesFileExists_U (   _In_ PWSTR  FileName    )`

believes that the file exists if get `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` status (note that `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` not equal `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) on file (after call `ZwQueryAttributesFile`), so i think will be enough correct do the same (but check for status instead win32 error).

in the end of end here always exist race condition by design. even if api exactly return to you that file exist - at the time when you got this code - file may be already deleted. or visa versa. so question - for what this need at all.

Comment: @ChrisD *8009030f 80090310 8009035e 8009035f c000001e c000001f c0000021 c0000022 c0000041 c000004b c0000056 c00000ba c00000d5 c000010a c0000121 c0000123 c000028a c000028b c000028d c000028e c000028f c0000290 c0000512 c000a203 c0130031* for example all converted to 5/